# Different activities use one non-activity class which needs to access the current running activity's instance variables and manipulate them

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B, and a non activity class C.

To use the methods of C, I create an instance c of C from the currently running activity (say A is in the foreground, and A has created C).

Now, I want to use the instance variables of activity A from c. What should I do?

I am trying to use the non activity C class for multiple activities. Please help me! I have researched it a lot, but still couldn't find anything useful about it. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Activity` object inside C constructor and initialize it using the `this` inside activity  A or B.

**Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            C myLocalCInstance = new C(this); //By using this you pass Activity object
        }
```

C class:

```
public class C{
  Activity mActivity;
  public C(Activity callingActivity){
   mActivity = callingActivity; // Use mActivity to do as you wish
  }
}
```

Comment: Your reply was really helpful. But when I try to use an instance variable of activity A (named "player1"), inside class C, it shows this variable in red color (probably because it doesn't recognize them). It shows, "Cannot resolve symbol 'player1' ". Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your code?maybe it would be easier to open a new question and tag me?

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance declare methods in class C as static

```
public class C{
  public static void exampleFuntion(){

  }
}
```

and then use from within A or B:

```
C.exampleFunction();
```

Comment: If I mark the methods of C as static, then I doubt if will be able to use the instance variables of activity A from those static methods (because, the variables which this static method uses, are created after an instance of the activity A class is created). What do you think?

Comment: you're right. In this case you need to provide the activity instance to the function as parameter. The function signature will be something like `public static void exampleFunction(Activity activity) {`